# Given two array create another one with only different element

Tags: javascript

I have two array:

for example:

```
arraySelectedItems = [{id: 1, name: "item1"}, {id: 2, name: "item2"}]
arraySavedItems = [{id: 1, name: "item1"}, {id: 2, name: "item2"}]
```

now I need to check if there is some item in arraySavedItems that is not present in arraySelectedItems, and in this case I'll go to populate another array called arrayDeletedItems.

If the two arrays have the same items I don't need to populate the arrayDeletedItems.

So I have tried with this code:

```
arraySavedItems.filter((itemSaved) => !arraySelectedItems.find((itemSel) => {
  if (itemSaved.id !== itemSel.id) {
    arrayDeletedItems.push(itemSaved)
  }
}
))
```

So with this data:

```
 arraySelectedItems = [{id: 1, name: "item1"}, {id: 2, name: "item2"}]
 
 arraySavedItems = [{id: 1, name: "item1"}, {id: 2, name: "item2"}]
```

I'll expect that arrayDeletedItems will be:

```
 arrayDeletedItems = []
```

Instead whit this data for example:

```
 arraySelectedItems = [{id: 1, name: "item1"}]

 arraySavedItems = [{id: 1, name: "item1"}, {id: 2, name: "item2"}]
```

I'll expect that arrayDeletedItems will be:

```
arrayDeletedItems = [{id: 2, name: "item2"}]
```

With my code I receive and arrayDeletedItems that has the all values:

```
arrayDeletedItems = [{id: 1, name: "item1"}, {id: 2, name: "item2"}]
```

Comment: just to clarify what is going wrong. Your code checks if any id's don't match and then add.
The thing is it will loop through ALL items in the arrays. In your last example with 1 selected item and 2 saved items it will loop through and say this in the first iteration: itemSaved.id (value:1) = itemSel.id(value:1) meaning it won't go into the if statement.
Now it will go onto itemSaved number 2. 
Now you'll see that 
itemSaved.id(value:2) = itemSel.id(value:1). This will go into the if statement since the values aren't equal

Comment: ye i have tried it in debugger and notice this. Thank you anyway for your explanation :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this generic function:

```js
function difference(a, b, keyFn) {
    let keys = new Set(a.map(keyFn))
    return b.filter(obj => !keys.has(keyFn(obj)))
}


//


selectedItems = [{id: 1, name: "item1"}, {id:4}]

savedItems = [{id: 1, name: "item1"}, {id: 2, name: "item2"}, {id:3}, {id:4}]

result = difference(selectedItems, savedItems, obj => obj.id)

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `.includes()` method on an array to check whether a value is contained in it (see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) for more information).

Now we can just filter the array of saved items to find only ones that aren't contained by the selected items array.

```js
arrayDeletedItems = arraySavedItems.filter((itemSaved) => 
  !arraySelectedItems.includes(itemSaved)
)
```

---

As @owenizedd points out in the comments, this only works for primitive data types where a shallow equality check is sufficient. A more robust approach can be used with the [`.reduce()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and a custom equality check. For example, [lodash's `isEqual()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual) does a deep comparison for equality. You would have to import the module for this. Unfortunately there is no native deep equality check in JavaScript currently (workarounds like `JSON.stringify()` to then compare the string representations have various downsides).

```js
arrayDeletedItems = arraySavedItems.filter((itemSaved) => 
  !arraySelectedItems.reduce((previous, current) => 
    previous || _.isEqual(current, itemSaved)
  )
)
```

Note that passing `previous` as the first argument to the 'or' operator (`||`) means we can benefit from lazy evaluation - once a hit has been found, the second half of the statement does not need to be evaluated any more.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that you can't compare object with another object because it will compare by reference, not by it's keys/values. `includes` works for primitive data types, but I don't think it would work for object

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem, since we have `id` we can utilize it.
You need a key that is unique. so `id` commonly known will have unique value.

So my approach, find items that is not exist in B array but in A array, and find items that exist in B but not in A array.

This approach not be the fastest, but the `findDiff` is reusable.

```js
const a = [....];
const b = [....];

const findDiff = (source, target) => {
   return source.filter((sourceItem, index) => {
      const isInTarget = target.findIndex(targetItem => targetItem.id === sourceItem.id)
      return isInTarget === -1
   })
}
const difference = findDiff(a,b).concat(findDiff(b,a)); //result
```